# regex match one instance of a pattern that repeats

Tags: ruby, regex, grok, logstash-grok

Given the following regex

```
/(500 Internal Server Error)/
```

How do we match only the 1st occurrence of this pattern in a single string that has many repeats of the same match?

For example:

```
Match 1
1.  500 Internal Server Error
Match 2
1.  500 Internal Server Error
Match 3
1.  500 Internal Server Error
```

How do we get 1. as our only answer?

Sample text for the match as follows (one big string on purpose)

```
[SoapUIMultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager$SoapUIDefaultClientConnection]     Receiving response: HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error12:09:26,638 INFO [SoapUIProTestCaseRunner] Assertion [Match content of [question]] has status VALID12:09:26,638 DEBUG [SoapUIMultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager$SoapUIDefaultClientConnection] Connection 0.0.0.0:41494<->23.6.55.1:80 shut down12:09:26,638 DEBUG [SoapUIMultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager$SoapUIDefaultClientConnection] Connection 0.0.0.0:41494<->23.6.55.1:80 closed12:09:26,638 INFO [SoapUIProTestCaseRunner] Finished running SoapUI testcase [Test_fieldsParameter], time taken: 384ms, status: FINISHED12:09:26,640 INFO [SoapUIProTestCaseRunner] Assertion [Match content of [errorCode]] has status VALID12:09:26,641 INFO [SoapUIProTestCaseRunner] Assertion [Match content of [message]] has status VALID12:09:26,641 INFO [SoapUIProTestCaseRunner] Assertion [Valid HTTP Status Codes] has status VALID12:09:26,641 INFO [SoapUIProTestCaseRunner] running step [OtherSortBy]12:09:26,643 DEBUG [HttpClientSupport$SoapUIHttpClient] Stale connection check12:09:26,645 DEBUG [HttpClientSupport$SoapUIHttpClient] Attempt 1 to execute request12:09:26,646 DEBUG [SoapUIMultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager$SoapUIDefaultClientConnection] Sending request: GET /api/review/v1/questions?prodId=570043&_sortby=other HTTP/1.112:09:26,666 DEBUG [SoapUIMultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager$SoapUIDefaultClientConnection] Receiving response: HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error12:09:26,667 DEBUG [SoapUIMultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager$SoapUIDefaultClientConnection] Connection 0.0.0.0:41475<->23.6.55.1:80 shut down12:09:26,667 DEBUG
```

Comment: What language/tool are you using? Otherwise you could add `.*` as a hack and capture group 1. Also remove `{1}`, it's redundant.

Comment: What is the problem that you are trying to solve here?

Comment: In JS, just do not use `g`, and you will capture the first occurrence. http://jsfiddle.net/32s0k4q2/. It makes no sense searching for the first occurrence of `/(500 Internal Server Error)/` regex matches as **all occurrences will be identical**.

Comment: .* captures everything that comes after the 1st match, doesn't work. @stribizhev , so it is not possible to regex a cherry picked match, is that what you are saying?

Comment: You have to give a reason why it won't work. Vague questions get like answers.

Comment: @bigoldrock again what tool/language are you using. This is getting annoying, you probably had a popup state that you should include it but you didn't. No wonder you're getting downvotes/close votes. Also if it's a specific language, don't forget to include the code.

Comment: Please show a sample input and your desired output.

Comment: @bigoldrock for the sake of argument: some tools match *all* by default and some would match the first occurrence by default. In some languages it would match the first one by default, you should add the `g` modifier to match all. In other, you have two different functions: one function to match all and the other to match a single. Do you get that randomly suggesting a language won't help you?

Comment: Can I ask why do you need this ?

Comment: It is for a grok in logstash. Rubular.com for testing the regex.

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look, this proves the string captured is the first:

```
str = "Match 1\n1.  500 Internal Server Error\nMatch 2\n1.  500 Internal Server Error\nMatch 3\n1.  500 Internal Server Error"
re = /(500 Internal Server Error)/
mdata = re.match(str)
puts mdata.begin(1)
puts mdata
```

Output of a [sample program](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/execute_ruby_online.php?PID=0Bw_CjBb95KQMLUhnd3QyQTRpYWM) proving it is the first occurrence (index of `12` in the input string):

```
12                                                                                                                                                                  
500 Internal Server Error
```